# Remove colons from Drupal form fields/labels

Tags: 7, theming, forms

How can I remove the : from appearing after every label in forms made with the Drupal Form API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create your own implementation of [theme_form_element()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6).
The offending semicolon is in `$t('!title: !required', ...)`, and would need to be removed in both locations.

Not the easiest thing to change, but at least it's possible without hacking core!

Answer (score 1):

The way I've just done it is to add a `<span class="colon"><span>` around the colon in field.tpl.php. Then I can hide it with `display:none;` if I don't want it.

It avoids putting a lot of logic into a tpl.php if you have multiple fields which either need or don't need colons.

It also allows you to change fields colon requirements on different pages. For example I often don't want them on displaying a node but would like them in editing.

Answer (score 0):

copy the field.tpl.php to your current theme folder and remove colon. Clear cache and check.
I think It will solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this also, works for me in drupal 7.

Drop this in the body of your version of 'page.tpl.php' in your template folder.

```
<?php
    drupal_add_js(
      'jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var labels = jQuery(".field-label");
        jQuery.each(labels, function() {
          this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(":", "");
        });
      });',
      'inline');
  ?>
```

Comment: Why was this voted down? Is it a valid way to remove the colons or not?

Comment: It was probably voted down because it's a client-side only solution. It would be far preferable to do this on the server side, as in Tim's answer

Comment: Note that this removes that character everywhere, and not only after the label